# R: How to use a "if"-like-function on vectors but no "ifelse" because if no it should do nothing

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization, conditional-statements

I try to overwrite multiple variables at once (months in a kind of calendar) with an value of another variable based on a condition of a third variable. If the condition is false, nothing should happen.

I thought the If-function would be helpful because one could omit the else but no, it does not work for vectors.

```
    DF1[,3:4] <- if (DF1$v7==5) {DFDF1$v5}  
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

On the other hand, fitting for a vector is ifelse, but it tells me

```
    DF1[,3:4] <- ifelse (DF1$v7==5, DF1$v5, )
"argument "no" is missing, with no default",
```

So what should I do to achieve my goal?

Thanks for any advice, beginners as me are grateful!

PS: Variables are just examples.

**EDIT:** I am looking for an way, where I can address the variables that should be replaced by column-number as in DF1[, 3:4] because otherwise I would have to type up to 12 different variable names (in my original DF).

Comment: My first thought would be to try `DF1[,3:4] <- ifelse (DF1$v7==5, DF1$v5, DF1[,3:4])`. However, there is a conceptual problem here: you try to replace two columns (3 and 4) with only one column (`v5` if you have a match). So you possibly have a problem not linked with if-like functions, but with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jealie - that was my first thought too.
In my real data, i try to fill a calendar with states (working, in school, no working) of every month in a 96 month period  with a variable of given working hours per Week for several months (v7) and the time of the interview (v5).
So my thought was to overwrite the states ([,3:4] standing for Jan&Feb of the first Year) with the working time to see where someone as working, but the working time is missing and to impute better afterwards. At the end the DF should be the basis for a optimal matching analysis.
**But I'd like a general answer best.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do one column after the other. Regarding the else condition, just use the original value

```
for (i in 3:4){
 DF[,i] <- ifelse(DF$v7 == 5, DF1$v5, DF[,i])
}
```

Comment: Is there another way for more complex data? Because when I want to apply this to 2 conditions, that i nest with each other (two ifelse's) its to much to handle for my system. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you change the ifelse condition to be complex?

Comment: Do you mean complex like more than one condition linked with boolean connectors as "&&"? I tried it, but one condition us a '"(all (is.na(DF1[,i]))"' and I don't know why but as a result all lines and rows are overwritten with the value of "then"/DF1$v5.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one way it might work:

```
 DF1[DF1$v7==5,3:4] <-cbind( DF1$v5,DF1$v5 )[DF1$v7==5, ]
```

The numbers of items on both sides of the assignment should match up. Tested. It delivered integer values when DF1$v5 was a factor but performed as intended. Could also do:

```
 DF1[DF1$v7==5,3:4] <- DF1[ , c('v5','v5')][DF1$v7==5, ]
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the second line of code. It works well with sample data, but what should one do, if one has for example 12 lines to fill. To type 12 'v5', as `DF1[DF1$v7==5,3:14] <- DF1[ , c('v5',''v5','v5','v5','v5','v5','v5','v5','v5','v5','v5',v5')][DF1$v7==5, ]` does not seem very elegant, does it?
That would be crucial to me, because I have to reproduce mostly more than 2 variables at once.

Answer (score 0):

This modifies the input in place:

```
> rif=\(x,y,z)do.call('=',list(substitute(x),ifelse(y,z,x)),,parent.frame())
> v=1:4;rif(v,v>4,-v);v
[1]  1  2  3  4 -5 -6 -7 -8
```

Or with magrittr:

```
> v=1:8;v%<>%ifelse(.>4,-.,.);v
[1]  1  2  3  4 -5 -6 -7 -8
```